# Using custom fonts and updating a textview's text as per locale, the expected text is not displayed unless application is restarted

Tags: android, android-studio

I have written a small sample app to test the updation of a text based on change in locales(English and Japanese).
I have also used custom fonts as shown in the link structure:
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYYx3.jpg)

The issue is that after switching the language of the device through the device's settings screen from english to japanese, the expected text is not displayed when switching back to my application. But after restarting the application, the expected text is displayed. I have attached screenshots of the same.

Expected output is that the text should change to the expected text without having to restart the application.

[Error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQWrF.jpg)

[Expected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c9q2.jpg)

Code for strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MY APPLICATION</string>
    <string name="language">language</string>
</resources>
```

Code for strings.xml(ja-rJP):

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MY APPLICATION</string>
<string name="language">言語</string>
</resources>
```

Code for the textview in activity_main.xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/language"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_light_global"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Note: I am aware that the text used in the xml file for japan is incorrect but that is part of my use case.